# Line missing in console when running SpringBoot application with H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am studying SpringBoot and when I run my SpringBoot application and when I check for my console for line:
**o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb',**
I see that no such line exists. However, when I open H2 console in my browser and enter "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" in JDBC URL segment, I find my tables, etc. Question is, why I do not have this line in the console when I run the application? In the course I am using this line appears in console. Should I somehow enable it? In course I'm told that JDBC URL must have value "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" and I am shown why (because in the console I am notified about that). But how can I know it if it is not in my console?

Answer (score 0):

Add devtools dependency, this will enable H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

In logs you can see following line:

```
o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:my-app'
```